ADC interrupt flag in ATmega2560
If we look to datasheet of ATmega2560
https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-2549-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf
In the ADC Section, page 285, it says the following:
"• Bit 4 – ADIF: ADC Interrupt Flag
This bit is set when an ADC conversion completes and the Data Registers are updated. The ADC Conversion
Complete Interrupt is executed if the ADIE bit and the I-bit in SREG are set. ADIF is cleared by hardware when
executing the corresponding interrupt handling vector. Alternatively, ADIF is cleared by writing a logical one to the
flag. Beware that if doing a Read-Modify-Write on ADCSRA, a pending interrupt can be disabled. This also applies
if the SBI and CBI instructions are used."
In the description, it says The bit is set when the conversion is complete, it means the bit is set to ONE when the conversion is compelte, yet it says ADIF is cleared by writing a logical one to the flag.
How a bit that is at logical ONE can be cleared by writing it to a ONE again ??
What did I miss the description ?

It does what it says it does; is there some confusion? Were you expecting different behavior? If so, please explain.

The register address you write and read do not need to be related. It is not a generic data storage register where you always read back what you wrote. For example UART data register will send out data you write, but on read it will return received data, so totally unrelated functiond even though they share a register address.
When reading, the read operation returns a status bit. It is the flag if conversion is done or not.
When writing, the write operation is a control bit. If control bit is 0 it does nothing, if control bit is 1 it clears the status flag.
Many other registers and bits are like this and it is normal. It's no different than any other register you read or write, you need to fully understand what you read and write for any other register too.
And, sometimes, you don't realize that you should not do a read-modify-write operation to a register or you will accidentally clear a status condition. Most spectacular results will happen when controlling the TWCR bits individually with read-modify-write operation.

I have used to use PIC16F Microcontrollers, and all the flags are set to one when the task is done by any module (ADC,Timers ...) and these flag bits have to be cleared by software (Reset to zero) in order to have another detection. That's why I have expected the flag bit of ATmega to be cleared when it is set to one at completion. Thanks for your explanation

@learndesign Sometimes you clear flag bits writing them zero, sometimes you clear them by writing one, sometimes they clear just by reading the status register. Datasheet will tell you which way to do it.

You miss that those are special function registers. They aren't RAM cells. They aren't wired the same way as RAM cells.
In this case, the internal D4 line is connected to the CLEAR input of the ADIF flipflop as well as to its output, and the internal R/-W line selects one or the other. So writing a 0 does nothing while writing a 1 activates CLEAR.
